# Get stream of data from mqtt using python(pyspark) in spark version 2.2.0

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, mqtt

I added the dependency in spark's POM.xml, given in the following link:

http://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/current/spark-sql-streaming-mqtt/

Built spark using maven again. But as we can see it shows only Java and Scala supports to get data from mqtt.

I want to get stream data from mqtt in **python.**
In earlier versions we had a pyspark.streaming.mqtt for the same.
What is the similar to this in **spark 2.2.0 pyspark**.
I am using mosquitto for mqtt broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PySpark you can use [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) bindings (you have to include Bahir jar):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()  # type: SparkSession
(spark
    .readStream
    .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
    .load("tcp://{}".format(broker_uri)))
```